# How to load jquery properties to extended template from base template, jquery included in base template

Tags: django, django-templates

i want to get jquery propertys from base template to extended template

headerfooter.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'medicure/images/favicon.png' %}" 
type="image/png" />
<title>Medicure</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="{% static 'medicure/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" 
rel="stylesheet">


 {% block headerfooter %}

 {% endblock %}



 <script src="{% static 'medicure/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
 <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <script src="{% static 'medicure/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"> 
 </script>
 <!-- FastClick -->
 <script src="{% static 'medicure/js/fastclick.js' %}"></script>
 <!-- NProgress -->
 <script src="{% static 'medicure/js/nprogress.js' %}"></script>
```

company.html

```
 {% extends "headerfooter.html" %}
 {% load staticfiles %}
 {% block headerfooter %}

  <script src="{% static 'masters/js/masters.js' %}"></script>
  {% endblock %}
```

in the above example i have included jquery in headerfooter.html, and i have included masters.js file in company.html,

in master.js javascript is working and jquery is not working,
if i include below script on top of masters.js then jquery is working fine, so i need to include jquery on every page even it is extended.

```
 <script src="{% static 'medicure/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include jquery before headerfooter  :

```
<script src="{% static 'medicure/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
 <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <script src="{% static 'medicure/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"> 
 </script>

{% block headerfooter %}

 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: that's fine i want with out including jquery on child class, if i include jquery script on top of masters.js then jquery is working fine, so i need to include jquery on every page even it is extended?

Answer (score 0):

Just put your block in after jQuery include

**headerfooter.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'medicure/images/favicon.png' %}" 
type="image/png" />
<title>Medicure</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="{% static 'medicure/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" 
rel="stylesheet">



 <script src="{% static 'medicure/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
 <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <script src="{% static 'medicure/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"> 
 </script>
 <!-- FastClick -->
 <script src="{% static 'medicure/js/fastclick.js' %}"></script>
 <!-- NProgress -->
 <script src="{% static 'medicure/js/nprogress.js' %}"></script>


 {% block headerfooter %}

 {% endblock %}
```